# Windows 8: How to Lock (not sleep) laptop on lid close?

Tags: windows-8, lock-screen, lid

If my laptop is connected to power source and is not configured to sleep on lid close (it is connected to power source and is working, I don't want it to sleep. It's compiling my code) if I close the lid, laptop will do nothing. This works as expected, but actually if I have my laptop connected to power source in the office it will be good to lock it if I close a lid. So no one can just open the lid and see my unlocked desktop.

I searched Google and it says that correct use case is to manually lock laptop via <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> every time before lid is closed. This is OK, but not very secure - after all, I can forget <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>.

Is there any easy way (maybe some registry value or app) to configure windows laptop so it will lock on lid close even without sleep? Of course I can write app/powershell script for this task, but this is not suitable for non-programmers end users.

Comment: For those interested, related question on SO [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486674/capturing-laptop-lid-closing-event-in-windows).

Comment: Related SU question: [Automatically lock screen on lid close in Windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/704520/automatically-lock-screen-on-lid-close-in-windows-7?rq=1)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no built in way to do this, but you could use [LidLock](http://download.cnet.com/Lid-Lock/3000-2094_4-76464070.html) for this purpose. It is a GUI tool which can help you what you want to achieve. You can also set it to start automatically with Windows  start-up.

[image]

[image]

You can also set the timer for sleep/hibernate after locking the laptop.

You can read more about this on this [article](http://sumtips.com/2012/10/automatically-lock-windows-computer-on-closing-laptop-lid.html).

Answer (score 11):

> 1. Using Run from the start menu, execute `regedit`.
> 2. Navigate to
>
>    ```
>    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SessionManager\Power
>    ```
> 3. Right click > New > DWORD (32 bits)
> 4. Rename it to `AwayModeEnabled`
> 5. Select it > Right click > Change value to `1` (Hexadecimal)
> 6. Go to the Power Options settings page and change the lid close action to sleep.

— **Source:** [Microsoft Answers - Lock computer on lid close?](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/lock-computer-on-lid-close/ba5616bc-2b7d-4fcb-a59d-9cf80b1021b9)

Comment: Checked on Windows 8: Not working, closing lid does nothing: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/239055/win8_laptop_lid_close_problem.png

Comment: Sure thing. I just restarted the laptop. closed lid, waited a few minutes and opened lid. Windows instantly displayed my desktop - so no sleep and no lock. Thanks about tag note, added it.

Comment: didn't work on Win10 even after restart. no extra option appeared on the drop down on 'lid close action'

Comment: Couldn't get it working on Win7 as of today. I have tried rebooting as well.

Comment: Windows 10 has a space or the article had a typo: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Power

Comment: this way sleep mode won't work as intended

Answer (score 11):

I wrote an alternative to the LidLock application suggested in other answers, called [LapLock](https://github.com/dechamps/laplock/). What it does is simply listen for the lid close event and lock the computer when the event fires. Compared to LidLock mine is very bare-bones (it doesn't even have a UI), but also more lightweight.

Answer (score 7):

Here is another way to do it:

Under `Choose what closing the lid does`, select `Do nothing` for `When I close the lid` option.

Now, go to `Change screen saver`, and select `Wait: 1 minutes` and check `On resume, display logon screen`

Now, after closing your lid, for one minute, nothing happens, then it gets locked.

Is that it? No, not exactly. This won't work when any program prevents screen saver: like windows media player or vlc etc.

So, I guess this isn't the perfect solution, but it is one :)

Comment: This is a good method, but: 1. screen saver will also pop up if i don't close the lid. It's not desirable since laptops are often used for reading etc. 2. If laptop is left at public place, i will need to wait this 1 minute after closing lid before leaving room. Otherwise, it will be a great security hole - any child can open the laptop after i leave and gain access to all my private information.

Answer (score -1):

The answer seems to be to change the power plan settings.

On your *More Power Options*, go to the plan you're using now, click *Change Plan Settings » Change Advanced Power Settings » Power Buttons and Lid* and change to *Never*.

Comment: Click on the battery icon visible on the taskbar of your Windows 8 computer screen and choose "More power options".

Comment: It have only "Adjust Screen Brightness", "Power Options", "Windows Mobility Center" and "Turn System icons on or off" :(. I'm using Windows 8 Professional 64-bit bought from Microsoft and installed myself, no system modifications.

Comment: Don't you have this option as found on [this image](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/More-Power-options.png)? Weird.

Comment: Changing the plan this setting to "Never" will not make the computer lock itself when the lid is closed. Therefore this is not an answer to the question.

Answer (score -1):

- Go to Power Management
- Choose your plan like *Power Saver*
- Click *Change plan parameters*
- On power settings plan click *Change advanced power settings*
- Locate the power button and lid, then two options come up: button and lid.
- Choose *Lid* and you will see the settings.

See also this video from Microsoft: [Change what happens when you close your laptop](http://windows.microsoft.com/is-IS/windows7/Change-what-happens-when-you-close-your-laptop)

Comment: The settings you're referring to do not include a "lock" option (only sleep, hibernate or shut down). Therefore you are not answering the question.

Answer (score -1):

Power Options--> Choose when to turn off the display (left hand side) -->  Change advanced power settings --> Balanced --> Require password on --> ****CHANGE NO TO YES****

Comment: At least here on Windows 10, there is no "Require password on" setting in the power plan advanced setting list.

Answer (score -1):

Window 10 RS4, enable a screensaver with a 3 minute timeout is my solution to a secure desktop/laptop. Sleep is no good for productivity apps running in the background. Closing the lid no longer has this basic option ... AwayModeEnabled did not work either.

```
> Right click on desktop
> Personalize
> Lock screen
> Screen saver settings
> Select your favourite design
> Wait 3 minutes
> On resume, display the logon screen
```

Answer (score -3):

This is actually built into the OS:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but i can't see anything about lock screen on your screenshot. Can you clarify, please?

Answer (score -3):

Go to **Control Panel**, making sure in the top right corner  where is says view by you are on **Large icons** and not **category**.

Then click on **power options** chose the side where it says "Choose what closing lid does."

Select sleep for both **Plugged in** and **On Battery** press **Save Changes**

Now open **Control Panel** again (still in large icon view) click on **User Account** then click on "Make changes to my account in PC settings"

Where it says "Require password after the display has been off for:" change this to **Always require password**

You are now done, so now when you shut your lid this will cause your computer to sleep which will cause your computer to lock.

Comment: But the question explicitly says: *"I don't want it to sleep"*. (Also, sorry, but the above is very hard to read. What about adding some paragraphs by using a blank line? And starting sentences with upper case characters?)

Comment: As i mentioned in my question, i don't want it to sleep: it's compiling code, so sleep = bad.