# How do I add this data to the registry? (Windows 8)

Tags: windows, laptop, windows-registry, power-options

While hunting around for a solution to the "Do nothing" power option for when the laptop lid is closed being absent, I came across this:

> By adding the registry keys:
>
> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Power\PowerSettings\4f971e89-eebd-4455-a8de-9e59040e7347\5ca83367-6e45-459f-a27b-476b1d01c936\3]
>   "Description"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,\
>   00,6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,\
>   5c,00,70,00,6f,00,77,00,72,00,70,00,72,00,6f,00,66,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,\
>   00,2c,00,2d,00,35,00,30,00,2c,00,54,00,61,00,6b,00,65,00,20,00,6e,00,6f,00,\
>   20,00,61,00,63,00,74,00,69,00,6f,00,6e,00,00,00
>   "FriendlyName"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,\
>   00,6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,\
>   5c,00,70,00,6f,00,77,00,72,00,70,00,72,00,6f,00,66,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,\
>   00,2c,00,2d,00,35,00,31,00,2c,00,54,00,61,00,6b,00,65,00,20,00,6e,00,6f,00,\
>   20,00,61,00,63,00,74,00,69,00,6f,00,6e,00,00,00
>
> "SettingValue"=dword:00000000
>
> the missing 'no action' option was available again (no reboot
>   required)!!!
>
> The value for 'Description' is:
>   @%SystemRoot%\system32\powrprof.dll,-50,Take no action
>
> The value for 'FriendlyName' is:
>   @%SystemRoot%\system32\powrprof.dll,-51,Take no action

But I have no idea how to do this. I have done some minor registry tweaking before, but they were for existing registry keys; this is adding new data, and I'm lost.

Can someone help, please?

- Nick

Comment: possible duplicate of [Close lid option "Do nothing" absent](http://superuser.com/questions/609194/close-lid-option-do-nothing-absent)

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your Desktop and make a new text file. Open it and paste the code in. Once that is done, go to File, Save As, and change`Save as type:` to `All files (*.*)`. For the file name put `value.reg`. After that simply double click on the file to add it to your registry.

Add the following, in the grey box, to the file:

> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Power\PowerSettings\4f971e89-eebd-4455-a8de-9e59040e7347\5ca83367-6e45-459f-a27b-476b1d01c936\3]
>   "Description"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,\
>   00,6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,\
>   5c,00,70,00,6f,00,77,00,72,00,70,00,72,00,6f,00,66,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,\
>   00,2c,00,2d,00,35,00,30,00,2c,00,54,00,61,00,6b,00,65,00,20,00,6e,00,6f,00,\
>   20,00,61,00,63,00,74,00,69,00,6f,00,6e,00,00,00
>   "FriendlyName"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,\
>   00,6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,\
>   5c,00,70,00,6f,00,77,00,72,00,70,00,72,00,6f,00,66,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,\
>   00,2c,00,2d,00,35,00,31,00,2c,00,54,00,61,00,6b,00,65,00,20,00,6e,00,6f,00,\
>   20,00,61,00,63,00,74,00,69,00,6f,00,6e,00,00,00
>
> "SettingValue"=dword:00000000

Comment: That didn't work. It's worked for others, but not me, so I'm obviously doing something different/wrong.

When you say "code", from where to where am I meant to be copy-pasting?
Do I have to manually key in some values somewhere after?

I tried asking the guy who came up with the solution, but Superuser says I need 50 Rep to comment on others' posts.

Here's the link to the page where I found the info:
http://superuser.com/questions/609194/close-lid-option-do-nothing-absent

The one by Nico Teering.

Comment: When you say it didn't work, what did it say exactly? I'll attach the copy-paste part to my answer, however this question will be closed soon because it is a duplicate. Let me know if it doesn't work for you. All you do is copy and paste that into the text document, then follow the steps to save it as a .reg.

Comment: @user285373 Also see the answer to the question you linked - will your air vents be obstructed if your lid is closed?

Comment: I know this is terribly late, but I just wanted to say I did end up getting it to work.

Thank you so much for your help.

Also, yeah, the vents sort of do get blocked. But I only ever do it when I need to move from one room to another, and keeping the lid up is inconvenient.