# Set Windows to prompt for password when opening lid, but not go to sleep

Tags: windows, passwords, wake-up, lid

I often plug my computer to my tv and close the lid, so I set 'Do nothing' when closing lid in the power options. However, I often close the lid when I walk away from my laptop in public places like libraries, and I want Windows to prompt for a password when I open the lid. Seems like it's only possible if the computer wakes up from sleep mode, not good for me.

How do I set Windows to not go to sleep AND prompt for password after closing the lid?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 8: How to Lock (not sleep) laptop on lid close?](http://superuser.com/questions/496295/windows-8-how-to-lock-not-sleep-laptop-on-lid-close)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automatically lock screen on lid close in Windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/704520/automatically-lock-screen-on-lid-close-in-windows-7?rq=1)

Comment: "I often close the lid when I walk away from my laptop in public places like libraries" -- you expect your laptop to be there when you come back?

Answer (score 3):

I do not believe that you can set Windows to auto-lock when closing lid and not going to sleep.  The only two options I can think of are:

Press Win+L  this will lock the computer immediately. Probably your best bet.

The other option is to set your computer to prompt you for password from the screensaver. This option is in your screensaver options.

Hope this helps.