# How can i download a file from virustotal for free?

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop, lock, lid

I want to download a file from virustotal.com

https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/655bde7f3c270b7b06e6c3dbba5c041727aec5389339f71b3ca73f80316212f9/analysis/

http://processchecker.com/file/LidLock.exe.html

Comment: If you're interested in that specific file check [Windows 8: How to Lock (not sleep) laptop on lid close?](http://superuser.com/a/527041/619267)

Answer (score 8):

VirusTotal doesn't offer regular users to download files at all. It's a free service for people to upload suspicious files and have them scanned by several antivirus softwares at once. Downloading submitted samples is possible, but only for individuals vetted by VirusTotal.