# Scheduling a task before sleep in Windows 7 and hold off the sleep event until task runs

Tags: windows-7, skype, sleep, scheduled-tasks

Note that this is different than the other questions I found (I did search), like: [Is there any way to execute something when closing the laptop's lid?](https://superuser.com/questions/146520/is-there-any-way-to-execute-something-when-closing-the-laptops-lid)

I used the same trick of scheduling a task on event #42 (System, Kernel-Power, Event 42), but the problem is that the task - at least in my case - is not actually run *before* going to sleep. it seems the schedule executes it and goes to sleep at the same time. if the task takes longer to execute, then tough luck.

I have a batch file which does:

```
@echo off
cd /d %~dp0
taskkill /t /im skype.exe
sleep 2
taskkill /t /f /im skype.exe
sleep 1
```

My task is **not** executed before going to sleep. The machine goes to sleep immediately as I can see the LEDs going off and hear the HDD click in less than 1 second, whereas I wanted it to hold of for 3 seconds before going to sleep.

It seems that tasks started by the scheduler are not holding off the sleep event -- and there are valid reasons for that (what if your task hangs?) -- but in my case, this is bummer!

Anyone knows of a way to make it work as intended above but being triggered by event 42?

Cheers

**NOTE:** I know I can create a batch/program/task which first kills skype, waits, and then sends a Sleep event but I would like to be able to trigger it using Event 42. Other users sometime log onto this machine while Skype is running in a different account and they send it to sleep using the normal Sleep entry in the start menu, not a custom batch/program.

**NOTE2** also tried with full paths for taskkill and sleep which are in Windows\System32. This kills Skype.exe then waits for 2 seconds then forcefully kills Skype.exe and then waits for another 1 second. This is due to a bug in Skype for Win 7 x64 which hangs Skype after waking up from Sleep. rather than waiting for Microsoft to fix this very old and frustrating and oh so overly-reported bug, I wanted to implement my own fix.

Answer (score 4):

Event 42 occurs too late (at the end of the process, no time to 
do anything useful) because it is intended as a "documentation"
for subsequent diagnostics, not a notification *before* things happen.
(I don't understand how could a MSFT moderator [advice it](https://superuser.com/a/320866/220675)?)

Unfortunately I haven't seen a working solution to your problem,
but I'm sure that Windows *does* provide a before-event notification,
although not in the Event log.
This means that you have to create/use an always-running background application
(~ a "daemon") that catches this pre-standby notification and then does
whatever you like.
I'm not aware of an existing application that can do this, neither
I know the relevant Windows APIs; but until a better answer is provided, here are some starting points that may help you in working out a solution:

- The following MSDN pages seem to lead to information about the notification itself:
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373233
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms703398.aspx#handling_sleep_transitions
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms701723.aspx
- If you don't want to dig into C++, then the [start_power_monitor](http://twapi.magicsplat.com/v3.1/power.html#start_power_monitor) command of the TWAPI extension of Tcl/Tk looks promising (see the **apmsuspend** event).
  [Tcl/Tk](http://wiki.tcl.tk) is not a complex product requiring installation and configuration, but rather a plain, very powerful [executable](http://www.patthoyts.tk/tclkit/win32-ix86/8.6.0/tclkit860.exe) that, when coupled with the single [TWAPI .dll](http://twapi.magicsplat.com/v3.1/installation.html), competes with PowerShell (with much lighter footprint) (Although surely PowerShell could cope with the problem, too, just I don't know the relevant commands/packages.)

UPDATE:

There's no way to “hold off the sleep event” because Microsoft has discontinued [PBT_APMQUERYSUSPEND](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372716(v=vs.85).aspx) that allowed it in XP and Vista. Instead, [now says that](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373208) you cannot prevent the user from putting the computer to sleep:

> Applications should respect that the user expects a certain behavior 
>   when they close the lid on their laptop or press the power button.

Only the [PBT_APMSUSPEND](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372721) event remained, after which

> The system allows approximately two seconds for an application to handle
>   this notification.