# Execute Script/Program on when Lid is opened on Laptop on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, laptop, lid

Is there any way to execute a script or a program on a Windows 10 laptop when the lid is opened (assuming the screen is not locked and a user logged in)?

Comment: Maybe in task manager using a trigger, not sure.

Comment: Similar question>>>>https://superuser.com/questions/146520/is-there-any-way-to-execute-something-when-closing-the-laptops-lid?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for the info! I read this question as well, but I suppose this wouldn't work, since it's based on that the laptop will enter "sleep mode" as soon as the lid is closed, which then will trigger an event and so on. There are no options to set what to do for when opening the lid in the power options as well.

Using a trigger in the event scheduler might work, but I wouldn't know which event gets triggered when the lid gets opened.

Comment: There has to be a way, just don't know what it is, maybe someone will have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set colMonitoredEvents = GetObject("winmgmts:")._
    ExecNotificationQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_PowerManagementEvent")
Do
    Set strLatestEvent = colMonitoredEvents.NextEvent
    If strLatestEvent.EventType = 4 Then 
        Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
        Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Process")
        For Each objItem in colItems
            If objItem.name = "Calculator.exe" then objItem.terminate
        Next
    ElseIf strLatestEvent.EventType = 7 Then 
        wscript.sleep 2000
        Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        WshShell.Run "calc.exe", 1, false
    End If
Loop
```

> Value Meaning
>   4 Entering Suspend
>   7 Resume from Suspend
>   10 Power Status Change
>   11 OEM Event
>   18 Resume Automatic

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-powermanagementevent